# The school/School is where I'm at

Tags: definite-article

Let's say an elementary school student is at their school, and says:

> a. I'm at school.

Here, I don't think you need any article:

> b. ?I'm at the school.
>
> c. ?I'm at a school.

Now, can sentence a. be rephrased as follows?

> d. School is where I'm at.

Or do you need now the definite article?

> e. The school is where I'm at.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody asks you on the phone where you are, and you say

> a I am at school

this means that you are currently at the school where you are enrolled as a student or that is your place of work.

> b I am at the school

this means that you are currently at the school that you have previously discussed with the questioner

> b I am at a school

this means that you are at a school, and there is nothing at all special about this particular school as far as you or the questioner are concerned.

If you rephrase the sentences as you suggested (though I can't think of any reason that you would want to), d would have the same meaning as a, and e would have the same meaning as b.

Note that the meaning depends on the question, for example:

> Q: What do you do during the day?
>   A: I am at school

this means that you are enrolled as a student at a school, but you might not actually be there at the moment. This is because present simple can also be used to describe regular or habitual actions.

Comment: When the speaker is enrolled as a student at a school, is it really okay for the student to use 'school' without any article as the subject of a sentence? As another example, can a student say _School has a lot of great teachers_?

Comment: @listeneva: I think that people would know what you mean, but I think that it's only after a preposition (at, in) that you can use **school** without an article to mean the place where you are enrolled or work. As a subject without article, I would assume that you were talking about schools in general, rather than the speaker's school. In your sentence, I  would say "**My** school has a lot of great teachers".

Comment: I think _School_ refers to the speaker's school and is used as subject without any article in sentence d. But you seem to endorse it. How come?

Comment: @listeneva In sentence d, **school** is grammatically the subject of the sentence, but semantically its meaning is determined by the **at** at the end of the sentence. And it's semantics rather than grammar that determines whether it's the speaker's school. And, yes, I endorsed it as grammatically correct but i **did** question why you would want to make convoluted sentences like d and e.

Comment: Because sentence d sounded okay to me even though _school_ was used as subject without any article.